# Calling a variable from a global class

Tags: c#

I have a class for global variables, like this:

```
internal static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static PortBrowserForm open;
}
```

The `PortBrowserForm` class is a Windows Form class that has a timer and want to use its properties, like this (in another form):

```
// In that other form...
GlobalVariables.open.timer1.Enabled = true;
```

But I cannot call it. I can only call a function from `GlobalVariables.open` variable (which is a form already). Please help.

Comment: You have to set the modifier of the controls inside the form to public.

Comment: `GlobalVariables.open` isn't a class - it's a variable. It's very unclear what's going on...

Comment: The timer is public, But Jon Skeet what should I do if I have a form like that and I need to access its timer?

Comment: "But I cannot call it." - what *exactly* happens when you try?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Apart from accessing the timer, of course. Why do you put the form´s definition in a separate static class?

Comment: @O.M.MApper : As usual you can see some recommendations by using "." operator on forms. I want to access the timer in that form, but it is not even recommended to me. @ John Willemse : I need that created form called open (which is already created from PortBrowserForm class) to be global.

Comment: @OneBytePerHour: Well, that is not a reliable thing to go by. What happens when you write the command and try to compile/run your project? (Also, please use tab completion when mentioning user names here on SO - otherwise, if the name is misspelt, the adressed users will not get notified about the message.)

Comment: Compiler -> Member 'WirelessBase.PortBrowserForm.portBrowser' (or my timer) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

Comment: @OneBytePerHour: Is your timer static then? What is `portBrowser`? Can you show/explain its declaration, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GlobalVariables.open.timer1.Enabled = true;
```

To make the above code work you need to make the `timer1`'s modifier `public` or atleast `internal`. But... Don't do that, never expose fields `public` because you don't get control over *who is doing what*.

Instead create a method which does the job for you.

```
class PortBrowserForm : Form
{
    public void SetTimerEnabled(bool enabled)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Then use

```
GlobalVariables.open.SetTimerEnabled(true);
```

Comment: "If you could access functions then why didn't you?", I said to my self! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick and Dirty

Check `PortBrowserForm .designer.cs/vb` file there you can find the declaration of all controls of the form. Change its access level to `public` from there and you can access that from any form just by creating forms instance.

### Update:

To access one forms control in another you need to pass the first form in the constructor of another. Suppose we have two forms

```
Form1.cs

Form2.cs

In some event of form1 , call form2.

frm1Btn_Click()
{
   form2 f2 = new form2(this);
   f2.Show();
}
```

Create a overloaded constructor in form2 with Form1 as parameter and pickup form1 and its all controls.

Comment: Quick and dirty.. ok, but better is to move declaration `form.designer.cs` to `form.cs`

Comment: Its access level is already declared as public. It is global and all of its variables and form controls are declared public too.